# Best way to capture all key events for a web application?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm a little distraught at the current state of key capturing for web applications. It works great as long as you know your user is going to be typing in a specific place (e.g. an `input` field), but as soon as you want to do global shortcuts for an entire "application", it seems to fall apart.

I'm trying to find out if there is a better way to capture *all* the key events for a web page than the method I am currently using.

My current method is to use the [JQuery Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) plugin, bound to the `document` element, i.e.:

```
$(document).bind("keyup", "delete", function() {});
```

That works great for most purposes, but for example on Firefox, if the user happens to absentmindedly move their mouse over the navigation bar, the delete key will sometimes result in the user going "back", and the key is never received by the handler so that I can stop propagation.

Is there a different element I should be binding to? Is there a better plugin out there for this? Should I just avoid using any keys that are bound to things in common web browsers?

As more and more web applications look to mimic their desktop counterparts, it seems like this is a basic feature that web developers will increasingly require.

**EDIT:** I should point out that I am already using `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()`. The main problem seems to be that sometimes the event is never even passed to the bound function. I am basically wondering if anyone has figured out a "higher" element to bind to other than `document`. Or is there an alternative I have never even thought of? Embedding an invisible Flash element on the page and then passing all keys from that to JavaScript, for example (I don't think this would work).

I think, at this point, I am doing things the "standard, well-known way." I am trying to see if there is an outside-the-box way that isn't widely known that maybe someone on Stack Overflow knows about :-).

Comment: Is it possible to force focus on a non-visible textbox? I would advise using keys that are commonly shared across browsers. Expecting a page not to go  back when you hit backspace is silly.

Comment: do you want to create short cuts or do u want to make kind of keylogging?

Comment: @helle I want to create shortcuts, not keylogging.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are making a sophisticated web-app with customized keyboard controls, the first thing you should do is alert the user that you are making a sophisticated web-app with customized keyboard controls. After that, *tell them* what the controls are and what they do.

Binding the `keypress` and `keydown` listeners to the `document` is the correct way to do it, but you have to remember to `preventDefault` and/or `stopPropogation` for keypresses that you want to override. Even if there is no default behavior, you will need to prevent them from cascading in case the user has rebound their default keyboard shortcuts.

Also, you will only be able to receive keyboard input when the page has focus.

When you say <kbd>Delete</kbd> I assume you mean the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key as <kbd>Delete</kbd> generally referrs to the key next to <kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

Edit to add:

**Be very careful** about which keys you choose to override. If you're making an app to be used by people other than yourself, you have to worry about usability and accessibility. Overriding the <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys is risky, especially for people using screen-readers. Make sure to test the site blind and fix any issues that may arise with traversing the page via the keyboard.

Comment: Yes I do mean Backspace, although I would bind this particular shortcut to both keys.

Comment: I am already using `e.stopPropogation` and `e.preventDefault`. The main problem seems to be that sometimes the event is never even "heard" by my event listeners. 

I agree about choosing which keys to override. I'm not looking to override Enter or Tab, etc. Mostly things like "hold Shift to constrain proportions when resizing", "press Delete/Backspace to delete this object", "press Ctrl+A to select all" -- the same sorts of shortcuts one would expect to use in a desktop application.

Comment: @Riley Dutton, the document is the "highest" level you can bind key events on a webpage. As I said in my post *you will only be able to receive keyboard input when the page has focus*. It's the same for flash. You may want to put a highlight or notice somewhere on the page so that a user can visibly tell when the page has focus and input.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use html-attribute `ACCESSKEY` and react onfocus. 
i.e.:

```
<input type="text" size="40" value="somefield" accesskey="F">
```

i think u might need to add a tabindex to tags like `<div>`

```
<div id="foo" tabindex="1" accesskey="F">
```

Comment: Accesskey would be nice to use, but its implementation is soo broken. It can conflict with the Browser's own hotkeys, and then it is bad for you.
[Read this for a simple example on that.](https://www.joedolson.com/2006/01/accesskeys-curse-blessing/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to events that happen where you have no control - e.g. the window chrome.  The way most webapps deal with this is asking the user to confirm their decision to leave the page, using the `onbeforeunload` event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var str = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?';
    e = e || window.event;

    if (userHasSomeUnsavedWork) {
        e.returnValue = str;
        return str;
    }
}
```

- [onbeforeunload - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

Comment: That will definitely be part of the strategy. I was just hoping to avoid a situation where the user gets that dialog box and thinks, "Wait, I wanted to delete this object, why is it telling me I'm going to leave the page?"

Answer (score -1):

Absolutly non-tested but... try it on 'window' element.